# How do I remove an icon from the top panel in GNOME Fallback mode?

Tags: icons, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

When I right click the Filezilla icon, the only options are "launch" and "properties". How do I remove it from the top panel?

[image]

Comment: I don't have the points to post an official answer, but one way to address this for Ubuntu 18.04 is to use the Icon Hider GNOME Extension: Open Firefox. Visit addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration. Click “Add to Firefox”. Install this package to enable it: `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`. Then use Firefox to visit extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider. Flip the switch from OFF to ON. Now a small icon with 4 squares will appear in the top right of your screen in the GNOME panel. Left click on it to toggle icons to hide.

Answer (score 99):

You are using the Gnome-Classic interface - either you are using this by choice, or you are using the *fallback mode* which occurs if your graphics card & driver doesnt the 3D Acceleration required for the full Gnome-Shell GUI.

To add and remove application launchers in the gnome-panel you need to:

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click the top menu bar - N.B. <kbd>Win</kbd> is the Windows Symbol key

If you are not using Compiz then you need to :

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click the top menu bar

Much more information is described in the linked Q&A and other links in that answer.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: It does not work when dconf: `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.mouse-button-modifier` is not `<Alt>`. I usually use `<Alt><Super>` and can't to remove something.

Answer (score 28):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while right-mouse clicking on the said icon.

A menu should then appear giving you the options to either ***move*** it or ***remove from panel***.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Worked on Ubuntu 16.04

`gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.lockdown locked-down false`

Comment: worked for me in 16.04