# How do I delete an unwanted icon in the bar at the bottom of the screen, in GNOME Classic?

Tags: gnome

Ubuntu 11.10 GNOME Classic

Left-clicking on the icon launches a [URL](http://download.tuxfamily.org/glxdock/mediacolor/album7/1316889806_55379c4c5c/DiskFree.tar.gz.png)

Middle-clicking on the icon (with the mouse wheel) doesn't do anything.

Right-clicking on an icon displays two options:

1. Launch
2. Properties

Clicking on "Launch" does the same as left-clicking on the icon.

Clicking on "Properties" displays three fields:

1. Name
2. Location
3. Comment

All three fields contain the same [URL](http://download.tuxfamily.org/glxdock/mediacolor/album7/1316889806_55379c4c5c/DiskFree.tar.gz.png)

Left-clicking, middle-clicking or right-clicking anywhere in an unused part of the bar at the bottom of the screen.

How do I delete the unwanted icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/91445/cant-remove-icon-from-top-bar, and probably more. Also, your update should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Originally posted by boxcorner:

> I discovered the arcane method is:
>
> - Alt + right-click
>
> Not exactly very intuitive, but it did the trick!

Comment: Ah.. secretly guarded ALT again!! Beats me why Gnome guys chose it like that.. without any hint whatsoever.