# How do you remove an icon from the GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove an icon from the top panel in GNOME Fallback mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91445/how-do-i-remove-an-icon-from-the-top-panel-in-gnome-fallback-mode)

One of my Ubuntu 12.04 users has switched from unity to gnome-panel (a.k.a. "Gnome Classic (No Effects)"), and came to me with this question:

One you've dropped an app icon onto the panel, how do you remove it?  I'm stumped.  I can get rid of everything by deleting the user's `~/.config/dconf/user` and `~/.cache/dconf/user`, but that's hardly an elegant solution.

Example:

[image]